# Set theory and computer science

Tags: algorithms, computation-models, mathematical-foundations

It's said that in [Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (ZFC) one can develop all of mathematics. How about computer science?

Is it possible to define algorithms as a first step? More specifically, how to define "if x = 1 then y else z"? How about loops?

Comment: Well, it's kinda misleading to say that ZFC allows to develop all of mathematics. There can be a consistent set theory $A: A\land ZFC$ is inconsistent.

Comment: You can define the semantics of programming languages in systems weaker than ZFC. I suggest picking up a textbook on programming language semantics.

Comment: To emphasize Yuval Filmus' statement, you can formalize typical computer science concepts in formal systems *far* weaker than ZFC.

Comment: Far, far, far weaker in fact.

Comment: $(1 - \mathrm{sgn}(x)) \cdot y + |\mathrm{sgn}(x)| \cdot z$, where $\mathrm{sgn}$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: @AndrejBauer: Then my question becomes: how to define sgn in set theory? You haven't got rid of the if-then-else structure, which is fundamental.

Comment: I can already predict that your next question will be "how to define everything in set theory", and in particular the real numbers, addition, subtraction, and the absolute value, once I point out that you should be asking about those as well. These are interesting questions, but the answers are general and well known, and long, so I suggest you look at a book on set theory. Perhaps someone can suggest one that explains the coding of mathematical objects using the cummulative hierarchy.

Comment: Very briefly: here is [coding of natural numbers in set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), here is [coding of ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory),  functions are sets of ordered pairs, integers are sets of ordered pairs of natural numbers, rationals are sets of ordered pairs of integers, reals are sets of rationals (Dedekind cuts). So the sign function is the set $\{(x,y) \mid (x < 0 \land y = -1) \lor (x = y = 0) \lor (x > 0 \land y = 1) \}$. I got rid of if-then-else, I think.

Comment: So it's about the expressiveness of first-order logic. Then how expressive is first-order logic, exactly? Any idea or reference, especially regarding CS concepts?

Comment: I fear Zirui Wang will discover our ability to use frameworks for syntax description to syntactically describe systems in which to model syntax manipulation derives from manipulating syntax.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends what you consider "computer science."

For what I would call "classical computer science" i.e. the theory of Algorithms, Turing Machines, etc. it can all be modelled in set theory.

A Turing Machine is just a tuple (which can be modelled using sets): a set of states, a tape-alphabet set, a transition function, etc. All of these are set-theoretic constructs, and even with nondeterminism, we replace the transition function with a relation, which is again set theoretic.

Similarly, we can define the semantics of programming languages using sets. Usually this just boils down to a big-step or small-step [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics), which again, is just defining relations.

Where things get iffy is with the so-called "alternate foundations of mathematics". This includes things like:

- [Martin-Lof type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory)
- [Coqand's Calculus of Constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions)
- [Homotopy type theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/)

They provide alternate sets of axioms from which mathematics can be built up. For example, the usually discard excluded middle and axiom of choice. Homotopy type theory, for example, introduces the Univalence Axiom.

These systems tend to be heavily oriented towards computation through the [Curry-Howard Correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), so that a proof can "run" on a computer. So they don't quite fit into ZFC, but are generally considered part of computer science.

Comment: I mean it's absolutely possible to develop all of these with set theory as the metatheory, so there's not really a conflict here.

Comment: How are types "iffy"? For me, they are right at the core of CS "feels".

Comment: @Raphael they're iffy in the sense that it's unclear whether something like HoTT belongs in Math, CS, or Philosophy, and unclear whether they are separate from ZFC (since they're an alternate foundation) or can be expressed in it

Comment: I think it's quite clear that HoTT belongs in Math, CS and Philosophy.

Comment: On technical side of things, HoTT models can be constructed in ZFC with a countable sequence of inaccessible cardinals. Inside HoTT, once can get a model of CZF (that was not a typo, it means "constructive ZF"), and since HoTT is compatible with excluded middle, we can in fact also get ZFC if we add excluded middle to HoTT. See the chapter on set theory in the HoTT book.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that is very well understood how type theory and set theory are related. There is no mystery.

Comment: @AndrejBauer feel free to edit the answer to clarify this

Comment: @AndrejBauer One could say that ZFC+Inaccessible Cardinals is not ZFC. However this is only necessary if we want to talk about arbitrary models of the various type theories (which, admittedly, we often do). If we just work purely syntactically, though, typical weak systems (i.e. weaker than ZFC) with maybe some transfinite induction thrown in should suffice.

Comment: Of course ZFC with inaccessible's is not ZFC! ZFC is not a holy cow. But if on one side you put a type theory with universes, then on the other side of the comparison you should be placing a set theory with universes as well. You may work syntactically, but that does not save you from consistency strength, and also, in order to prove strong normalization in the presence of universes you need some pesky transfinite arguments.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I figured you'd respond along the lines of your first two sentences with which I completely agree. However, it seems reasonable to say CoC, say, "[doesn't] quite fit into ZFC" if it requires ZFC+Inaccessibles. I also completely agree with regards to consistency strength, and I should be clear that only *some* meta-theoretical properties can be established in weaker systems. The thrust of my comments is that to *work within* these systems only requires being able to check if a derivation is valid, and *that* meta-theoretic property usually doesn't require much of the metatheory.